# Sum column based on two columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to create a new column that will sum the overall Value(£) for each port for the Length Groups "10m&Under" and "Over10m"

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far based on your own research, and what went wrong with your attempts? For instance, the pandas [DataFrame.groupby()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) method seems appropriate here

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
df[df['Length Group'].isin(["10m&Under", "Over10m"])].pivot_table(values='Value(£)', index='Port of Landing', aggfunc='sum')
```

Comment: Surely that wont great a sum for value for each Length group, for each port?

Comment: @WillMarshall That's right didn't notice the port thing. Thanks. Updated.

Comment: seems to give me a empty table with Port of Landing as the only column

Comment: @WillMarshall My bad, check the update.

Comment: is there a way to also include the Length group in there you can view which group the value is for?

Comment: i would like the table to include a colum for the Year, and Port of landing also